# How to use regex groups in Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I need to replace string 'name' with fullName in the following kind of strings:

```
software : (publisher:abc and name:oracle)
```

This needs to be replaced as:

```
software : (publisher:abc and fullName:xyz)
```

Now, basically, part "name:xyz" can come anywhere inside parenthesis. e.g.

```
software:(name:xyz)
```

I am trying to use groups and the regex I built looks :

```
(\bsoftware\s*?:\s*?\()((.*?)(\s*?(and|or)\s*?))(\bname:.*?\)\s|:.*?\)$)
```

Comment: Please check https://regex101.com/r/81r4Wq/2, `\b(software\s*:\s*\([^()]*)\bname:\w+` => `$1fullName:xyz`

Comment: Thanks, that works. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(software\s*:\s*\([^()]*)\bname:\w+
```

and replace with `$1fullName:xyz`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/81r4Wq/2) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cb(software%5Cs*%3A%5Cs*%5C(%5B%5E()%5D*)%5Cbname%3A%5Cw%2B):

[image]

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(software\s*:\s*\([^()]*)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern is a placeholder for the value captured in this group):

  - `software` - a word
  - `\s*:\s*` - a `:` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
  - `\(` - a `(` char
  - `[^()]*` - 0 or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\bname`  - whole word `name`
- `:`  - colon
- `\w+`  - 1 or more letters, digits or underscores.

Java sample code:

```
String result = s.replaceAll("\\b(software\\s*:\\s*\\([^()]*)\\bname:\\w+", "$1fullName:xyz");
```